# Error running pod install when update to flutter 3.0.1

Tags: ios, flutter, cocoapods

I try to run an app on the ios simulator but I got this error
I think get this error after I update Flutter to 3.0 and update the Xcode too.
I tried to run this command `sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi`   then `flutter clean`  `flutter run`  like everybody suggested but it doesn’t work.

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Storage":
  In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
    Firebase/Storage (= 8.11.0)

  In Podfile:
    firebase_storage (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_storage/ios`) was resolved to 10.2.15, which depends on
      Firebase/Storage (= 8.15.0)

Specs satisfying the `Firebase/Storage (= 8.11.0), Firebase/Storage (= 8.15.0)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

Comment: Update: I haven’t do anything yet but the problem has solved it self. Since I've upgrade Xcode and Flutter somehow I run it again and there’s was no error. I guess the best way to solve it is just to wait.